# How to send an email with a get request

Tags: php, get, request

I tried to send an email with a get request, when I click on a link.
When I compare the email the result is always negative.

This is my request (example):

..?email=test@test.com

```
$checkCode = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM USER WHERE email='$email'");

$result = '';
if($checkCode === $code){
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE USER SET available=true WHERE email='$email'");
}
```

but it doesn't work. I think that the problem is the get request.
How can I do? 
Thanks!

Comment: What are $email and $code?

Comment: $email = $_GET['email']

Comment: Do you use $_GET['email'] somewhere before your code? Could you show some more code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value using $_GET variable first:

```
if (isset($_GET['email']) && $_GET['email'] != '') {
    $email = $_GET['email'];
}
```